# How to inspect a Firefox extension's element using Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to extract a link from the notification of an extension using Selenium to test many websites.

The extension I am testing is this example in github [full code available here](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/notify-link-clicks-i18n), which shows the clicked link in a notification if a user clicked a link in any of Mozilla's websites.

background-script.js

```
/*
Log that we received the message.
Then display a notification. The notification contains the URL,
which we read from the message.
*/
function notify(message) {
  console.log("background script received message");
  var title = browser.i18n.getMessage("notificationTitle");
  var content = browser.i18n.getMessage("notificationContent", message.url);
  browser.notifications.create({
    "type": "basic",
    "iconUrl": browser.extension.getURL("icons/link-48.png"),
    "title": title,
    "message": content
  });
}

/*
Assign `notify()` as a listener to messages from the content script.
*/
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(notify);
```

manifest.json:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "__MSG_extensionName__",
  "description": "__MSG_extensionDescription__",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/notify-link-clicks-i18n",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/link-48.png"
  },

  "permissions": ["notifications"],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background-script.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],

  "default_locale": "en"
}
```

contentscript.js

```
/*
If the click was on a link, send a message to the background page.
The message contains the link's URL.
*/
function notifyExtension(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  while ((target.tagName != "A" || !target.href) && target.parentNode) {
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
  if (target.tagName != "A")
    return;

  console.log("content script sending message");
  browser.runtime.sendMessage({"url": target.href});
}

/*
Add notifyExtension() as a listener to click events.
*/
window.addEventListener("click", notifyExtension);
```

I want to collect the notification text (the link) when it appears. I will input many websites in Selenium.

My question is: how can I inspect the notification using Selenium? When I right click on the notification, I do not get options similar to those in the browser. so I am unable to locate the element name to use with Selenium. Any hints will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notifications created by the extension belong to the operational system, not the browser. You won't be able to inspect them like a normal HTML element.

What you can do is to listen to `browser.notifications.onClosed` or `browser.notifications.onClicked` events and get that information in the extension code.

References:

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/native-mac-os-notifications
- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/richNotifications#behave
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications

Comment: I use Firefox extension not Chrome

Comment: It's the same thing since Firefox WebExtensions implements the chrome namespace. I edited my answer though.

Comment: Ok. But if I listen to events, and get info. from the extension, can I extract them using Selenium? that is my question. It is clear of course in the extension I can get these info and use them in the extension. But I need to automate the process using Selenium.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that, because the `notifications` API trigger the operational system notifications. They don't belong to the browser.

Comment: thanks. But if I used other things (not notification, say open new tab and write the info there instead of notification), can I search about the tab title for example from the Selenium (although the Selenium originally opened a first tab, say for: google.com, but the extension opened  a new tab and wrote some info. which I want to get).